# Python Pandas not able to read file from Other folder

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyqt5

I am trying to write GUI program using pyqt5 and pandas to select folder, read all html files from the folder consolidate it in one pandas dataframe and output an excel file.

I have written the code, and its working fine when selecting the file from the same directory where the code is.

The only problem is its giving "No table found" Error if when I select file from a different directory.

Please check the error code below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\prince\Desktop\Gui\final\UI.py", line 69, in go
df = pd.read_html(file)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line          906, in read_html
keep_default_na=keep_default_na)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line    743, in _parse
raise_with_traceback(retained)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 344, in raise_with_traceback
raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
ValueError: No tables found
[Finished in 17.8s with exit code 1]
```

PFB the code

```
import sys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui(self)
    def init_ui(self,Consolidate):
        Consolidate.setObjectName("Consolidate")
        Consolidate.resize(410, 300)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Consolidate)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 220, 381, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Consolidate)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 30, 51, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("browse")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Consolidate)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 291, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Consolidate)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 250, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("go")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Consolidate)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 351, 141))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Consolidate)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Consolidate)

    def retranslateUi(self, Consolidate):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Consolidate.setWindowTitle(_translate("Consolidate", "Consolidate Excel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Consolidate", "Browse"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Consolidate", "Please Browse The Target Folder"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Consolidate", "Go"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.fname)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.go)

        folder = str()
    def fname(self):
        global folder
        file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Folder"))
        folder = (file)
        print (folder)
        self.lineEdit.setText(folder)

    def go(self):
        import pandas as pd
        dflist = list()
        fnames = (os.listdir(folder))
        counter = 0

        for file in fnames:
            if file == "Consolidate.py" or file == "QtoolAssigned.xlsx":
                continue
            else:
                print(file)
                print(folder)
                df = pd.read_html(file)

                self.textBrowser_2.append(file[7:-28])
                df = pd.read_html(file)
                df = df[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=4)
                df['Team Name'] = str(file[7:-28])             
                dflist.append(df)
            concatdf = pd.concat(dflist,axis=0)
            concatdf.to_excel(folder+'\\'+'QtoolAssigned.xlsx', index=None)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is caused because you need to pass the full path of the file, as you pass only the name of the file then pandas will look for it in the folder where the GUI is executed, the solution is to pass the complete path for that we use `os.path.join()`

```
def go(self):
    import pandas as pd
    dflist = list()
    fnames = (os.listdir(folder))
    counter = 0

    for file in fnames:
        if file not in ["Consolidate.py", "QtoolAssigned.xlsx"]:
            print(file)
            print(folder)
            df = pd.read_html(os.path.join(folder, file))
            self.textBrowser_2.append(file[7:-28])
            df = df[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=4)
            df['Team Name'] = str(file[7:-28])             
            dflist.append(df)
        concatdf = pd.concat(dflist,axis=0)
        concatdf.to_excel(os.path.join(folder, 'QtoolAssigned.xlsx'), index=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  that fixed this issue, m having another issue while converting this script to .exe file..

Comment: @NaveenSingh When an answer is correct you should mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. When you do, I will help you with your new problem

Comment: sorry about that..  I'm new to stackoverflow or new to coding itself.. I tried pyinstaller but not able to make executable file.. m using python 3.6 all required libraries installed.  and the program works perfectly file using python interpreter..

Comment: And what is the problem you have when using pyinstaller?

Comment: I am not able to open the exe file created by pyinstaller.. in my VDI m getting error "Failed to execute script" and in my PC it says "This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in " ". "

Comment: search where you have installed PyQt5 if there is a folder called plugins, and within this there must be another folder called windows, add that path to the windows environment variables, and run back.

Comment: still no luck..  I am getting same error msgs on both the systems

Comment: dell vostro.. windows 7 ultimate.. python 3.6, pyqt5